# Calling asynchronous function from dash

Tags: flask, async-await, python-asyncio, plotly-dash

Once a single `function` needs to be `await`ed, it seems like a cascading of `functions` that need to be `await`ed, until you reach a point where adding `await` breaks stuff:

I have `dash` code that intermittently gets called:

```
def get_data(symbolStr):
    print("Getting AR for", symbolStr)
    df = amp.get_data_job(symbolStr) #calls async code and need to be awaited
    return df
```

...

```
html.Div(
        dcc.Interval(id='interval1', interval = 900 * 1000, n_intervals=0),
       
    ),   
html.Div(
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id='table',
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in magic_columns],
            editable=True,
            row_deletable=True
        ),
    ) 

@app.callback(
    [dash.dependencies.Output('table', 'data')],
    [dash.dependencies.Input('interval1', 'n_intervals')],
    [dash.dependencies.State('table', 'data')]
    )

def update_interval(n, data):
    allSymbolsDf = pd.DataFrame()

    for symbolStr in symbolsStr:
        df = get_data(symbolStr)
        allSymbolsDf = allSymbolsDf.append(df)
        time.sleep(3)
   
    return [allSymbolsDf.to_dict('rows')]
```

Thing is, `get_data` is a `function` that calls `asynchronous` code

```
df = amp.get_data_job(symbolStr)
```

I can't turn the callback `update_interval` into an `asynchronous` `function` (AFAIK). What is the recommended way out of this. I mean, still keeping `dash`.

Comment: Dash is Flask, Flask is not async framework, why do you need to use async functions in multithreading web server like Flask?

Answer (score 5):

Ran into the same situation using FastApi and serving dash on the side. Use asyncio.run()

```
import asyncio

async def asyn_fun(foo):
    return True if foo == "bar" else False

def sync_fun(foo):
    return asyncio.run(asyn_fun(foo))

print(sync_fun("bar"))
```

Comment: You can improve `return True if foo == "bar" else False` by simplifying it into `return foo == "bar"`